# Getting a value error when removing .activate and .select

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that filters for certain data in a large workbook and then pastes it into a workbook containing just that kind of data.  Initially, I wrote the code using .select and .activate, but have since then tried to move away from that.

Here is the code using .select

```
    Workbooks(DataFileName).Sheets(twttgtdata).Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks(ShopFileName).Sheets(twttgt).Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Here is the optimized version of that code that does the same thing.

```
        With Workbooks(DataFileName).Sheets(twttgtdata)
            On Error Resume Next
          .ShowAllData
          Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
            Destination:= Workbooks(ShopFileName).Sheets(twttgt).Cells(Workbooks(ShopFileName).Sheets(twttgt).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

As far as I can tell, these two blocks of code do the exact same task.  However, when using the latter code, it makes a bunch of formulas in the workbook have a #value error.  The former does not.  I've pretty thoroughly investigated and am almost certain that it has nothing to do with formatting or number type.  What am I missing?  Does intersect do more than I'm understanding?

More info can be provided if it would help.  Not sure what else to do to diagnose this.

Comment: I found `Intersect` volatile. In your with loop, can you try: `.UsedRange.Copy Workbooks(ShopFileName).Sheets(twttgt).Range("A1")`. Start of your target range can replace `Range("A1")`

Comment: Why are you using .ShowAllData then copying xlCellTypeVisible cells? If you want to copy filtered data, then copy xlCellTypeVisible. If you want to copy all cells then just copy it.